# Hudson job SVN authentication error

Tags: svn, authentication, weblogic, hudson

I am using Windows7 + Hudson 3.0.1+ VisualSVN server + TortoiseSVN client

When I try to enter "Repository URL" in hudson job, it getting error as below:

> Failed to authenticate: svn: E170001: OPTIONS of '/svn': 401
>   Authorization Required (https://) FAILED: svn: E170001: Authentication
>   failed for https://*/trunk*
>   org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: E170001:
>   Authentication failed for

I have tried with various options like:

1. i am able to login SVN url using same credentials in browser.
2. deleting .subversion folder in .hudson folder
3. directly entering credentials in `http://localhost:7101/hudson/scm/SubversionSCM/enterCredential`
4. Also i have tried with various previous forum posts and their suggestios, but nothing worked as far.

I have deployed hudson 3.0.1 war file on weblogic 10.3.5 server as an application.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like error wording you've specified is incomplete or even includes incorrect URL `https:///trunk`. So what URL do you enter in Hudson? What is the exact error wording?

As well, it's important to know what authentication type you have enabled on VisualSVN Server.